# Ogre SDK exception occured

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, ogre3d

I've setup Ogre and dependencies on my PC, and downloaded some Ogre applications. When I launch my new exe file of the project I just downloaded it generates the following error:

```
05:37:59: Loading library C:/OgreSDK_vc9_v1-7-1/bin/debug\RenderSystem_Direct3D9_d
05:37:59: OGRE EXCEPTION(7:InternalErrorException): Could not load dynamic library C     :/OgreSDK_vc9_v1-7-1/bin/debug\RenderSystem_Direct3D9_d.  System Error: The specified module  could not be found.

in DynLib::load at ..\..\..\..\OgreMain\src\OgreDynLib.cpp (line 91)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked that the file it wants to load actually exist, and in the path given?

Comment: So you are saying I should properly configure my cfg files?

Comment: Also, write down some answer, so I can declare it as the proposed one, since I have figured out, based on your words, how to get it working. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Upon creation of the central Ogre3D class [Ogre::Root](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/html/classOgre_1_1Root.html), you need to pass the name of a *.CFG file that contains all to be loaded Ogre plugins, such as the above mentioned D3D9 Render System.

That file needs to be next to your *.EXE by default and should look like this (in a minimal form where only the D3D9 Render System is loaded and the matching DLL file resides next to this CFG file):

```
# Defines plugins to load

# Define plugin folder
PluginFolder=.

# Define plugins
Plugin=RenderSystem_Direct3D9
```

For more information, have a look at this [section in the Ogre3D tutorial 1](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Basic+Tutorial+1#Configuration_Files)

Answer (score 0):

This took me a while until I figured it out. The dll (RenderSystem_Direct3D9_d) is missed because you didn't build it - it's the project with the same name (RenderSystem_Direct3D9) in the OGRE.sln

I'm using OGRE 2.1, so the dll I missing is RenderSystem_Direct3D11_d.dll  instead of RenderSystem_Direct3D9_d.dll like yours, but the fix is similar, just build that dll's project, like the image below.
[image: OgreMain_RenderSystem_Direct3D11]

Anyway, as a beginner, to avoid any trouble, just hit F6 to build whole solution.